# Avoid formatting comments

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there anyway to avoid formatting the comments?

To reproduce, paste below example SQL code to BQ:

```
--important comment on table info

select * from mytable1;

/* some more 
multiline
important comment 
on table info:*/

select * from mytable2;
```

It will look like this:

[image]

Now, click on "MORE", then "Format query"

[image]

Some words in comments get capitalised, like "table", "on" and become part of SQL code:

[image]

Comment: i copy/paste your example into BQ UI and see no problem! looks like your sample text and screenshot are not in sync! not same

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant hmm, I triple checked it before posting this question. I will test again next week and update.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I tried again, edited the post, step by step on how to repro.

Comment: sure, i see the problem now. in your original post you've missed to mention use of MORE >> Format Query :o)